# Using DirectoryInfo in C#

Tags: c#, text-files, directoryinfo

If there a more efficient way to do the following:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");
newFileName = Path.Combine(di.FullName, "MyFile.Txt");
```

I realise that it’s only two lines of code, but given that I already have the directory, it feels like I should be able to do something like:

```
newFileName = di.Combine(“MyFile.txt”);
```

EDIT:

Should have been more clear - I already have the path for another purpose, so:

```
DirectoryInfo di = MyFuncReturnsDir();
newFileName = Path.Combine(di.FullName, "MyFile.Txt");
```

Comment: This doesn't need fixing, it is already as compact and reliable as it can get.  You could write it in a single line, makes it less readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just do `newFileName = Path.Combine(@"c:\", "MyFile.Txt");`?

As you say, you already have the path.

Comment: I've edited my post - I have the DirectoryInfo object for a reason

Comment: @pm_2: I'm not sure that it would make things better, but you could always write `newFileName = Path.Combine(MyFuncReturnsDir().FullName, "MyFile.Txt");` if you want it on one line.

Comment: I just wanted to see if there was a more efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

@ho1 is right.

You can also write an extension method (C# 3.0+):

```
public static class DirectoryInforExtensions
{
  public static string Combine(this DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, string fileName)
  {
    return Path.Combine(di.FullName, fileName);
  }
}
```

and use it by doing

```
newFileName = di.Combine("MyFile.txt");
```